# Select and deselect many options at once in CheckboxBar

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

Is there any way to select and deselect many parameters in Manipulate's CheckboxBar? For instance, consider following code:

```
Manipulate[
 lst = Flatten@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, CharacterRange["a", "j"], 
    CharacterRange["A", "G"]};
 
 lst[[part]], 
 {part, Thread[Range[Length@lst] -> Flatten@lst], 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
 Button["select All numbers", part = Range@5], 
 Button["select all lowercase", part = Range[6, 15]],
 Button["select all capital", part = Range[16, 22]]
 ]
```

I can select many numbers/letters with one button, but I can't  combine number with letters (when I click other button, the first deselects). How to avoid that and select and select parts at the discretion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to preserve already checked options, you can use [`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html).

```
lst = Flatten@{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, CharacterRange["a", "j"], 
    CharacterRange["A", "G"]};

Manipulate[
 lst[[part]], {part, Thread[Range[Length@lst] -> Flatten@lst], 
  ControlType -> CheckboxBar}, 
 Button["select All numbers", part = Union[part, Range[5]]], 
 Button["select all lowercase", part = Union[part, Range[6, 15]]], 
 Button["select all capital", part = Union[part, Range[16, 22]]]]
```

Comment: great idea! Now I can deselect then in easy manner using Delete: ```Button["deselect all numbers", part = Delete[part, {#} & /@ Range[5]]]```

Answer (score 3):

```
lists = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"},
   {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"}};

lst = Flatten[lists];

indices = TakeList[Range[22], {5, 10, 7}];
```

FWIW, an attempt to make a custom `TogglerBar` with ragged layout and `Select/Deselect All` buttons attached to rows:

```
Manipulate[a,
 {{a, {1}, Rotate[Style["SELECTION", "Panel", Gray, 14], 90 Degree]},
  lists, 
  Panel @ raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[#, lists] &}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[a,
 {{a, {1}, Rotate[Style["SELECTION", "Panel", Gray, 14], 90 Degree]},
  lists, 
  Panel @ raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[#, lists, Automatic, Left] &}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Grid[{Prepend["part "] @ part, 
      Prepend[StringForm["lst[[``]] ", part]] @ lst[[part]]}, 
     Dividers -> All], 
 {part, {1}, Rotate[Style["SELECTION", "Panel", Gray, 14], 90 Degree]}, 
 indices, Panel @ raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[#, indices, lists] &}]
```

[image]

---

#### Code

```
ClearAll[toggleAddRemove, raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove, toRagged, 
  raggedTogglerBar, addRemoveTogglerBar]

toRagged[dims_, side_ : Automatic, spacings_ : Automatic] :=
  Module[{s = side /. {Automatic | Right -> PadLeft, _ -> PadRight}, 
     rs = spacings /. {Automatic -> 0, _ -> First[spacings, spacings]},
     cs = spacings /. {Automatic -> 0, _ -> Last[spacings, spacings]}},
    RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. GridBox[x_, o___] :> 
       RuleCondition[GridBox[side[#, Automatic, ""] &@TakeList[First@x, dims],
         "RowSpacings" -> rs, "ColumnSpacings" -> cs, 
         BaselinePosition -> Center, o]]]] &


raggedTogglerBar[Dynamic[xx_], values_, labels_ : Automatic, side_ : Automatic, 
   size_ : Automatic, spacings_ : Automatic, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DynamicModule[{v = Flatten @ values,
   lbls = Flatten[{labels /. Automatic -> values}], 
   lengths = Length /@ values}, 
  toRagged[lengths, 
    side /. {Automatic | Right -> PadLeft, Left -> PadRight}, 
    spacings]@
   TogglerBar[Dynamic[xx], Thread[v -> lbls],
    ImageSize -> size /. Automatic -> {25, 25},
    Alignment -> Center, Appearance -> "Horizontal", opts]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{raggedTogglerBar[Dynamic[q], lists], Dynamic[q]}, "\[VerticalSeparator]"]
```

[image]

```
raggedTogglerBar[Dynamic[r], 
 TakeList[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {7, 3, 5, All}]]
```

[image]

```
raggedTogglerBar[Dynamic[r], 
 TakeList[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {7, 3, 5, All}], 
 Automatic, Left]
```

[image]

Add/remove button icons:

```
addAllButton[size_ : 25] := Show[ColorReplace[
   ToExpression @ FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "SquarePlusIconMedium"], 
  {GrayLevel[0.7019607777695525] ->  Darker@Green}], 
 ImageSize -> size]

deleteAllButton[size_ : 25] := Show[ColorReplace[
   ToExpression @ FrontEndResource["FEBitmaps", "SquareMinusIconMedium"], 
   {GrayLevel[0.7019607777695525] -> Red}], ImageSize -> size]

Row[{addAllButton[90], deleteAllButton[90]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
SetAttributes[toggleAddRemove, HoldAllComplete]

toggleAddRemove[var_, v_] := If[IntersectingQ[var, v],
   var = DeleteCases[var, Alternatives @@ v],
   var = DeleteDuplicates[Join[var, v]]]

addRemoveTogglerBar[Dynamic[var_], vl_, size_ : Automatic,
  spacings_ : Automatic, opts_ : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 DynamicModule[{sz = size /. Automatic -> {25, 25}, 
     sp = spacings /.  Automatic -> {0, 0}},
   If[! ValueQ[var], var = {}];
   If[! ListQ[var], var = {}];
   Grid[Table[With[{v = v},
     {Setter[Dynamic[IntersectingQ[var, v], 
        toggleAddRemove[var, v] &], {True},
       Dynamic[IntersectingQ[var, v] /. 
         {True -> deleteAllButton[sz], _ | False -> addAllButton[sz]}],
       Appearance -> None, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> sz]}], 
    {v, vl}], 
   Spacings -> sp, BaselinePosition -> Center]]


raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[Dynamic[xx_], values_, labels_ : Automatic,
   side_ : Automatic, size_ : Automatic, spacings_ : Automatic, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Row[(side /. {Automatic | PadLeft | Right -> Identity, _ -> Reverse})@
   {raggedTogglerBar[Dynamic[xx], values, labels, side, size, spacings],
    addRemoveTogglerBar[Dynamic[xx], values, size, spacings, opts]}, 
  Spacer[1]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{Panel[raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[Dynamic[w], lists], 
   Background -> LightBlue], Dynamic[w]}, "\[VerticalSeparator]"]
```

[image]

```
Row[{Panel[
   raggedTogglerBarWAddRemove[Dynamic[z], lists, Automatic, Left],
    Background -> LightBlue], Dynamic[z]}, "\[VerticalSeparator]"]
```

[image]